# My objective is to predict the next 3 events of each id_num based on their previous events

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction, data-analysis

I am new to data science and I am working on a model that kind of looks like the sample data shown below. However in the orginal data there are many `id_num` and `Events`. My objective is to predict the next 3 events of each `id_num` based on their previous `Events`.

Please help me in solving this or regarding the method to be used for solving, using R programming.

[image: sample data]

[image: My Objective]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest "prediction" is to assume that the sequence of letters will repeat for each `id_num`. I hope this is in line what the OP understands by "prediction".

The code

```
library(data.table)
DT[, .(Events = append(Events, head(rep(Events, 3L), 3L))), by = id_num]
```

creates

> ```
>     id_num Events
>  1:      1      A
>  2:      1      B
>  3:      1      C
>  4:      1      D
>  5:      1      E
>  6:      1      A
>  7:      1      B
>  8:      1      C
>  9:      2      B
> 10:      2      E
> 11:      2      B
> 12:      2      E
> 13:      2      B
> 14:      3      E
> 15:      3      A
> 16:      3      E
> 17:      3      A
> 18:      3      E
> 19:      3      A
> 20:      3      E
> 21:      4      C
> 22:      4      C
> 23:      4      C
> 24:      4      C
> 25:      5      F
> 26:      5      G
> 27:      5      F
> 28:      5      G
> 29:      5      F
>     id_num Events
> ```

`data.table` is used here because of the easy to use grouping function and because I'm acquainted with it.

#### Explanation

For each `id_num` the existing sequence of letters is replicated 3 times using `rep()` to ensure enough values to fill at least 3 next values. But, only the first 3 values are taken using `head()`. These 3 values are appended to the existing sequence for each `id_num`

#### Some tuning

There are two possible optimisations:

1. If the sequence of values is much longer than the number of values to predict `n_pred`, simply repeating the long sequence `n_pred` times is a waste.
2. The call to `append()` can be avoided if the existing sequence will be repeated one more time.

So, the optimised code looks like:

```
n_pred <- 3L
DT[, .(Events = head(rep(Events, 1L + ceiling(n_pred / .N)), .N + n_pred)), by = id_num]
```

Note that `.N` is a special symbol in `data.table` syntax containing the number rows in a group. `head()` now returns the original sequence plus the predicted values.

#### Data

```
DT <- data.table(
  id_num = c(rep(1L, 5L), 2L, 2L, rep(3L, 4L), 4L, 5L, 5L),
  Events = c(LETTERS[1:5], "B", "E", rep(c("E", "A"), 2L), "C", "F", "G")
)
DT
```

> ```
>     id_num Events
>  1:      1      A
>  2:      1      B
>  3:      1      C
>  4:      1      D
>  5:      1      E
>  6:      2      B
>  7:      2      E
>  8:      3      E
>  9:      3      A
> 10:      3      E
> 11:      3      A
> 12:      4      C
> 13:      5      F
> 14:      5      G
> ```

Comment: Yes I got you point. But the data with which I am working got many events (around 3000 events) and there are around 6000 id_num. Is there any generalised way of doing this?

Comment: This should work for an arbitrary number of events and id_nums. The only hardcoded variable is the number of values to predict which can be modified easily.