# selecting multiple index from vector

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a vector containing say 30000 elements.

I want to get a new vector out of it which will have 15000 elements from index 1:5, 11:15, 21:25 and so on till 29991:29995.

How can I do it using "R programming"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
r1 <- unlist(lapply(seq(1, length(v1), by = 10), function(i) v1[i:(i+4)]))
```

---

Or a vectorized option would be

```
r2 <- v1[(seq_along(v1))*rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(5, 5))]
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- rnorm(30000)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you guide me me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250893/my-objective-is-to-predict-the-next-3-events-of-each-id-num-based-on-their-previ

Answer (score 0):

use this code. . first check

```
x<-1:100
(y<-x[c(rep(T,5),rep(F,5))])
```

according to that

```
 x<-rnorm(30000)
 y<-x[c(rep(T,5),rep(F,5))]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250893/my-objective-is-to-predict-the-next-3-events-of-each-id-num-based-on-their-previ